# javascript error on internet explorer 6,7,8, " is null or not an object "

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

when I start my index.php it calls my javascript file that has this code below:

[image]

when the application starts immediately this error appears:

[image]

and this can only happen on the internet explorers, there is no 'txtName' on index.php, because the. js is called for every page, there any way to improve this function ? tath i dont need to  put manually the js in each page?

Anyone know how can I solve this ? Thank you very much...

Comment: It means that IE can't find your element (with id='txtName'). More code (with HTML markup) will help us to understand why

Comment: I added the answer to the question in the original text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you put a conditional for this method:
In this case:

```
var iId = document.getElementById('txtName');
if(iId != null)
{
   // Processing
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

After the updated question - you can test for the element first

```
function focus(){
  var txtNameObj = document.getElementById('txtName');
  if(txtNameObj){
    txtNameObj.focus();
  }
}
```

This should avoid the error with it not being defined.

**Original**

I can only guess there is one of two problems:

a.) Your DOM hasn't loaded yet (so even though that ID will exist, it doesn't yet)

b.) You do not have an element with that ID.

If the element does exist, be sure to only call the focus function once you are sure that the element is loaded. e.g. you could place it as a script tag just before the body close.

```
    <script>
      focus();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because script tags are synchronously executed, or are 'blocking', you can also put the script immediately after the element needed in the source.