# Internet Explorer javascript value NULL, or not object

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-8

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135321/javascript-error-on-internet-explorer-6-7-8-is-null-or-not-an-object) topics, but not solved my problem.

Here is my code what is working fine in `Chrome` and `Firefox`, but in `Internet Explorer` not working (tested only in IE8):

```
var myjson = {'dat':[
    {'myval':'100','price':'1300'},
    {'myval':'100','price':'950'},
    {'myval':'20','price':'100'},
    {'myval':'0','price':'1000'},
    {'myval':'100','price':'750'},
]};
var myotherval = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < myjson.dat.length; i++) {
    if ( (myjson.dat[i].myval == 0 || myjson.dat[i].myval == 0) && myotherval == 0 ) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The Internet Explorer say `is NULL, or not an object`. Every variable has value every time. Several times they are `0`.

Anybody has any idea? Where can I find the error?

Comment: Needs more code and the unparsed json

Comment: difficult to see any error without your JSON Struct.

Comment: IE8 can't handle the extra dot at the end of the last `dat[]`, this makes your `myjson` null. Though this should cause `] needed` error before the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

```
myjson.dat[i].myval
```

is an integer. Use http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

```
parseInt(myjson.dat[i].myval) == 0
```

Comment: hmm .. post a bit more code. the structure of the myjson and how you create that object

Comment: I fail to see the relevancy